# Intuitive way to set mouse wheel scroll speed / "number of lines to scroll" in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: gnome, mouse

Is there an intuitive way to change the mouse wheel "lines to scroll" setting in Ubuntu 18.04 / gnome? I've browsed a little and came across various (partially pretty old) discussions pointing to `imwheel`, but isn't there a gnome setting to achieve this? I was hoping to find a GSettings key under `org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.mouse` like `wheel-lines-to-scroll`, but didn't. Am I missing out something?

Please don't downvote me for posting a Windows10 screenshot here... but here is how this looks over there:

[image]